# how to use order by clause with union clause in oracle when we need to sort using upper(column name)?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

The below query is giving error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dealer_state
FROM A
WHERE country='SS' 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT dealer_state
FROM B
WHERE country='SS'
ORDER BY upper(dealer_state)
```

How to sort using upper(column) in order by clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the "error" your query is giving is that it's not ordering records from `B` amongst records from `A` as you had expected, you need to make your `UNION` query a subquery to one that performs the ordering:

```
SELECT dealer_state FROM (
    SELECT dealer_state FROM A WHERE country='SS' 
  UNION
    SELECT dealer_state FROM B WHERE country='SS'
) t
ORDER BY upper(dealer_state)
```

Comment: The error is coming:The derived table expression is missing a correlation name. Check derived table syntax in the Reference Manual.

Comment: The DISTINCTs are redundant in the presence of the UNION

Answer (score 1):

The leftmost expressions in `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` must match.

Easiest way is to do the following:

```
SELECT dds FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT dealer_state AS dds FROM A
     WHERE country='SS'
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT dealer_state AS dds FROM B
     WHERE country='SS') AS d
ORDER BY upper(dds);
```

Comment: The error is coming:Order-by items must appear in the select-list if the statement contains set operators.

Comment: Right. I think @eggyal answer is what you need.